# How to calculate total exp SQL

Tags: php, sql, database, count, row

```
CREATE TABLE `snake_game` (
`user` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`timerun` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`variable1` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`variable2` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`variable3` varchar(65) NOT NULL default ''
)
```

how do I calculate the total exp (variable2) using PHP?
Like calculating the total exp of all users (total exp of user1, of user2 etc...) -> total exp
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the summation

```
SELECT SUM(variable2) FROM snake_game
```

and then call this statement from `PHP`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(variable2) FROM snake_game");    
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```